# Why has shoulda controller test assign_to no access to instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing, shoulda

For my Rails 3 application I use FactoryGirl together with shoulda context (1.0.0.beta1) and matchers (1.0.0.beta3) for my functional tests. 
My problem: in the code example below, the assign_to test fails because @user - to my surprise - turns out to be nil. In the outer setup block, @user is assigned a valid model instance, but from within the should assign_to statement the instance variable is not accessible. Why is that and what is the correct way to write that test?

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "as admin" do
    setup do
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
    end

    context "getting index" do
      setup do
        get :index
      end

      should assign_to(:users).with([@user])
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, seems like a bug.  It only happened after updating from 3.0.0.beta2 to the latest git HEAD.  However, I need the latest version from master since a release has not been made in over a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that passing the value as a black miraculously works.  However, after digging into the actual [AssignToMatcher code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/action_controller/assign_to_matcher.rb), it doesn't seem to make sense why the parameter method wouldn't work while the block method would.

For the sake of the +250 rep I'm investing in this, I'd still like an answer that explains why the param method isn't working (and how to fix it), but until then, at least I have a workaround.

@dblp1, hopefully this works for you too.  Here's an example specific to your code:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "as admin" do
    setup do
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
    end

    context "getting index" do
      setup do
        get :index
      end

      should assign_to(:users).with { [@user] }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would first remove the square brackets `should assign_to(:users).with(@user)`. It seems that there was a bug on this exact topic (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/157). If it still does not work, it is a bug and you should reopen the issue. Why with the block works it is clear to me. :-) I hope it helps.

Comment: Good catch on the issue.  That seems to explain why this method is working over the param method, though I don't know why it's still an issue for me considering I've got the latest release.

Comment: it *shoulda* have been fixed :-). What is the exact error message?

Comment: When I use the param method instead of the block method, I get an error along the lines of: `Expected action to assign nil for user, but got #<User id: 17, email: "test23@example.com" ...>`

Comment: It's worth noting that I'm using the latest release of shoulda (3.0.0), which was released a couple days ago.  I was using the latest github version prior to that, so I shouldn't still be running into issue #157 that you linked to, unless the error somehow made it back into the code.  I don't see how that's possible though since the [AssignToMatcher hasn't been updated in 11 months](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/de11b4b59bed0cdd79e4b958f378d9d3c3c1d598).

Answer (score 0):

(I am pasting as an answer as it is fairly long)

I mocked a bit your test and checked what was the results passed.

Interestingly enough, when I call the matcher `@post=null` (as I believe in your case). The issues I think (after a while of investigation), it coming from the the order the `setup do` block is called and the fact that the variables defined in one context are not visible in the nested context.

modified class

```
context "as admin" do
 setup do
   @post = Post.new
   puts "Step 1 - inside setup do"
   puts @post.class
 end
 puts "Step 2 - outside setup do 1"
 puts @post.class

 context "getting index" do
   setup do
     get :index
   end
   puts "Step 3 - calling shoulda"
   puts @post.class
   should assign_to(:posts).with([@post])
   #should assign_to(:posts).with  { [@post] }
   end
end
```

And the results in the console

```
ruby -I test test/functional/posts_controller_test.rb
Step 2 - outside setup do 1
NilClass
Step 3 - calling shoulda
NilClass
Loaded suite test/functional/posts_controller_test
Started
Step 1 - inside setup do
Post
```

So the setup cycle is called at the end (and not at the beginning) and then your is Nil when passed to the matcher.

Even if I remove the first `setup do` does not work pretty well.

```
Step 1 - inside setup do
Post
Step 2 - outside setup do 1
Post
Step 3 - calling shoulda
NilClass
```

Finally, putting the post in the inner context

```
Step 3 - calling shoulda
Post
```

If you call `@user = Factory.create(:user)` directly inside the "getting index" context, I believe it will work.

Comment: I know that makes it look like it's working out of order, but it's not.  It requires a bit of deeper understanding about how [blocks](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) work.  Just because any given block is defined prior to one of your `puts` calls does not mean that it will be called/evaluated prior to the aforementioned `puts` calls.  It simply means that the block was defined first, but its calling order could come at any point.   Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

When you are working with indexes you should use the plural of the instance variable.

`@users` rather than `@user`

You should also populate it as an array.

Finally, Shoulda matchers should start with "it" and be contained in braces, at least in the RSpec world, which is what I use.  Not sure if this is the case with Test::Unit or whether your formatting above will work.

Try something like this.

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  context "as admin" do
    setup do
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
    end

    context "getting index" do
      setup do
        @users = Array.new(3) { Factory(:user) }
        get :index
      end

      it { should assign_to(:users).with(@users) }
    end
end
```

Comment: Your suggestions are syntactical preferences and will not change the outcome.  Unfortunately, it is an actual issue and has nothing to do with the naming of the variables.  Also, the `it` method is part of Rspec, not Test::Unit.